# How to redirect request with data to another url in Flask

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I have a Flask app that redirects the requests to different urls checking their availability first. The target URLs do not belong to the same Flask app.

I am already able to redirect to the available url, but I am having problems trying to pass the data that came in the original request.

I am working with this code:

```py
@app.route('/<path:text>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main(text):
    urls = ['https://<PLACE-1>/api/ping', 
            'https://<PLACE-2>/api/ping']
    for url in urls:
      print('Testing url: ' + url)
      resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

      if resp.status_code != 200:
        print('The status code of '+ url + ' was ' + resp.status_code)
        continue

      data = json.loads(resp.content)
      if data != 'pong':
        print('The response from ' + url + ' was: ' + data)
        continue

      url = url.replace('/api/ping', '/' + text)
      print('Redirecting to: ' + url)

      return redirect(url, code=301)

    return 'Backends are not available :('
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: The urls used in the URL list, are they both URLs from this very same Flask project ?

Comment: No, they aren't.
I was checking the possibility to use `url_for`, but it is for URLs from the same Flask project.

Comment: My lucky guess is the code never gets past the `data=json.loads()` line. Give me a minute let me draw up my answer below.

Comment: You have routes for both GET + POST. Which one is causing you grief? Does the "data" arrive as `?x=1&y=2` query arguments, or is there some `multipart/form-data` encoding going on here, and the client won't re-send it upon `302` ?

Comment: @J_H, the problem is with the POST. I am trying to pass the info that comes in the property `request.json` to the selected target.

Comment: Have you tried using the redirect with a 307 status to signal the browser to send the exact same request to the given url?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see is in these two lines

```py
      data = json.loads(resp.content)
      if data != 'pong':
```

`json.loads(x)` runs an error when x is not a valid json string. If the expected value for data really is `pong`, then an error like this one will be thrown at that point:

[image: json error]

Then if "pong" is really the data you receive, then it should not go past that point. you are better off just running with `if data.content != "pong"`

If it's not being thrown, then you might like to add some more information or turn your debugger on to find what might be going on.

Other than that,  everything should be fine.

Comment: In this case the `json.loads(resp.content)` is working because the `resp.content` type is byte, not string. If you test this `json.loads(b'"pong"')` the load function will return `"pong"`.  

I am able to reach the line `return redirect(url, code=301)` without problems.